# Ubuntu 14.04 Wi-Fi suddenly fails

Tags: 14.04, wireless, intel-wireless

When I'm working with my laptop suddenly wi-fi disconnects, when I restart my laptop then I can't enable wireless, I can't even see the option to enable it, I just can connect via wire. This has been working good ultil a couple of days ago. Shut down for a long time solves the problem, but after a couple of hours it happend again.
I don't know if this is because temperature or something else.
This is happening in an Asus Zenbook UX305.

I have tried reintalling `network-manager` package.

This is the error I got (Enable connection failed):

[image]

This is the output for `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 59
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:f7000000-f7001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 9c:eb:e8:22:ae:5e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.08.1 (2015/07/28) duplex=full ip=192.168.1.37 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```